# За пределами функции map выдает не полный массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, search

Вот код. Мне нужно что бы при начинании ввода какой-то песни её полное название выводилась в `div` но почему-то второй `console.log` постоянно возвращает название второй песни а в `div` и вовсе ничего не выводиться. Подскажите, в чём ошибка?

```js
var songs = [{
    artist: {
      name: 'Imagine',
      song: 'Dragons'
    }
  },

  {
    artist: {
      name: 'Five',
      song: 'Finger'
    }
  }
];

var song, name;
songs.map(function(item) {
  song = item.artist.song;
  name = item.artist.name;
  console.log('fisrt', song);
});
document.getElementById('search').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('founded').innerHTML = '';
  var length = this.value.length;
  if (length > 0) {
    console.log('second', song);
    for (var i = 0; i < song.length; i++) {
      var show = song[i].split('').slice(0, length).join('');
      if (show == this.value) {
        document.getElementById('founded').innerHTML += song[i] + '</br>'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search" />
<div id="founded"></div>
```

[image: Так выглядит songs]

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю, но у вас `song` - это не массив. Ваш `songs.map` вообще непонятно что делает о_О

Comment: @Suvitruf взгляние на скрин котрый я добавил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Что происходит в данном коде?

```
songs.map(function(item) { ... })
```

вызывает метод [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), который *возвращает новый массив* и его значение нигде не используется.

Внутри коллбэка для  [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) присваивается значение переменным `song` и `name`. Таким образом, их значения **всегда** будут соответствовать значениям в последнем элементе массива `songs`, а именно:

```
song == Finger
name == Five
```

Стоит обратить внимания, что значения являются строками.

Далее идет цикл **по `song`**, то есть перебираются буквы строки `"Finder"` и единственный вариант ввода, для которого выполнится условие - "F".

---

### Что надо было сделать?

Задачу, которую пытается решить приведенный код можно сформулировать так:

> выбрать из массива элементы, в которых значение поля `song` начинается с введенной строки, вывести значение `song`.

1. Для выборки элементов из массива удобно воспользоваться методом [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

   ```
    songs.filter(song=> ... )
   ```
2. Для определения того, что одна строка начинается с другой можно воспользоваться методом [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) или [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

   ```
    song.artist.song.startsWith(value)
   ```
3. Для получения списка состоящего только из песен можно применить метод [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

   ```
    .map(song => song.artist.song)
   ```
4. Для вывода, можно собрать полученные элементы в строку через разделитель `<br>`, с помощью метода [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

   ```
    .join('<br>');
   ```

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```js
var songs = [{
    artist: {
      name: 'Imagine',
      song: 'Dragons'
    }
  },
  {
    artist: {
      name: 'Five',
      song: 'Finger'
    }
  },
  {
    artist: {
      name: 'Four',
      song: 'FingerPrint'
    }
  }

];

document.getElementById('search').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('founded').innerHTML = '';
  var length = this.value.length;
  if (length > 0) {
    document.getElementById('founded').innerHTML = songs.filter(song => song.artist.song.startsWith(this.value)) // сравнение с учетом регистра
      .map(song => song.artist.song)
      .join('<br>');


  }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search" />
<div id="founded"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение, ответ шикарный, всё делает так как я и хотел!!!

Comment: @МаксимБуяков, обрати внимание, что `startsWith` регистрозависима, то есть в слове `Finger` не будет найдена буква `f`.

Comment: я понимаю, спасибо)